# Analyze in excel feature doesnt work in SSAS Tabular

Tags: ssas, tabular

I'm using SSAS Tabular in Visual studio 2017. I am unable to open the model using "Analyze in Excel" feature. Everytime i click on "Analyze in Excel", an blank instance of excel opens up and nothing happens. It doesnt open an excel sheet or anything.I am using excel 2010.Not sure what is going on. Any help? thank you.

Comment: Hello

I have the same issue.
How did you solve it ?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi from Microsoft® Analysis Server® Feature Pack
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=55264